# Why is Rails redirecting my POST but not GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I'm trying to post data to a certain `controller#action` pair, but my app redirects me on POST (but not GET), and I can't figure out why.

I built a bare-bones controller with one method:

```
class NavigationsController < ApplicationController
    def foo
        render :text => 'in foo'
    end
end
```

My routing file has only one rule:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

Here's my result when I GET and POST, though:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000/navigations/foo/1
in foo
$ curl -d 'a=b' http://localhost:3000/navigations/foo/1
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

*specs: rails 2.3.8, ruby 1.8.7*

Comment: Do your logs show anything interesting?

Comment: Nothing. Just that I'm being redirected.

Comment: Please list your gems and plugins.

Comment: A reasonable instruction. The problem was with the `protect_from_forgery` injunction, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `protect_from_forgery`.

### For all controllers

Commenting out (or delete) `protect_from_forgery` in ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    #protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
    # ...
end
```

### For one or more controllers

Add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to the controller declaration.

```
class NavsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
    # ...
end
```

### For one or more actions

Add an `:except` option to the foregoing `skip_before_filter` or `protect_from_forgery` commands.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery :except => :index
end

class MyOtherController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :except => [:create]
end
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with accepting your own answer. This issue seems useful to others as well, so please consider not deleting it.