# PHP REQUEST_METHOD POST turns into GET

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-5.4

I'm trying to extend an old web application which uses CodeIgniter 1.7 (I know...) and am running into some trouble. I want a certain route to only be accessible via a *POST* request. So at the top of the function I have the following;

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    die ('Wrong request method: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
```

Locally, on PHP 7.0.14 with PHP's built-in web server, this works fine. In production, however, on a CPanel-managed server running PHP 5.4.25, it doesn't.

When sending a *POST* request to my route with Postman, I get the following;

> Wrong request method: **GET**

*PUT*, *PATCH*, *DELETE*, ... requests all get recognised correctly. *POST* requests, however, seem to magically become *GET* requests.

*POST* data I sent with the request seems to disappear as well and is not to be found in either `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

It seems to not be related to the CodeIgniter framework however as when I call a file outside of the framework I get the same result.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possibly the same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268863/laravel4-post-unexplained-redirect-to-get (not sure it is a duplicate though).

Comment: Any mod_rewrite rules?

Comment: Also, check access logs, if there was a redirect. It's quite common to respond with 302 after processing POST requests to avoid form re-submission by page reload.

Comment: Definitely check LSerni's link, was gonna suggest the same problem, but depends on specific server configuration, could get redirected to an URL **with** slash from the one without.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was making requests to http://domain whcih was set up to redirect to http://www.domain, which as it turns out turns POST requests into GET requests. And Postman does not notify the user of such redirects happening.

If you're running into this problem, make sure to check whether there's any redirects happening.

I wonder why this only happens with POST requests, however, and not with PUT, PATCH, DELETE, ... requests.

Thanks to LSerni, Alex Blex and Vaviloff for pointing me in the right direction.