# Vue js , http 405 error Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, http, vue.js

I have a problem with the http calls in my api.

The thing is that i have this http POST call:

```
axios.post("/api/crear/dimension/", data).then((response) => {
                        this.success();
                        console.log(response.data);
                    }).catch((response) => {
                        this.error(response)//;
                    })
```

*Using axios because vue resource is getting deprecated.*

the thing is that when i want to trigger the call this happens :

```
GET http://localhost/api/crear/dimension 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

***Notice how chrome takes this as GET call instead of a POST one. IDK why***

But when i do a GET call everything works fine.

this is my route file in laravel:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
  Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
  });

  Route::post('/crear/dimension/', 'AdminController@createDimension');
```

});

PS : Im using the passport package in laravel. Everything is configured well 
because i can get a GET call with no problems. The thing is in the POST call,

I did a put , patch call too. Same result as above,

i have tried with vue resource aswell but nothings works

//EDIT

I removed the slashes from the end of the api calls and i got a 401. 
For more info go [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268863/laravel4-post-unexplained-redirect-to-get)

Comment: I have the same error, did you find any solution?

Comment: yes. You have to remove the last slash in the api call in laravel and in your api call with axios or whatever you using.

Comment: I made a gist for you explaining the whole thing https://gist.github.com/pilsoftTeam/093980487651a27d28df034dbd27a3fb

Answer (score 1):

`vue-resource` isn't being deprecated, it's simply no longer officially supported by `Vue`. `Laravel` automatically defines an interceptor for `vue-resource` so the `csrf_token` is automatically passed, you will find the following in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = Laravel.csrfToken;

    next();
});
```

If you are using a different ajax library then you will need to pass this `csrf_token`. I don't use `axios` but from their docs you will probably need to include something like this in your `bootstrap.js` file:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
   config.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = Laravel.csrfToken;
   return config;
});
```

Comment: But does this explains why i can do GET calls even with axios ? But POST with any of them

Comment: A post requires a `csrf_token` in laravel otherwise you will receive a `405 error`, I'm not sure why chrome is telling you it's a `GET`, I assume  `axios` is well tested, so it may just be something internal.